# Cosmos DB- "Resource Not Found error - while updating partition key property"

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am getting below error while updating the partition key field's value.

> [7/8/2020 2:02:00 PM] [Error] - Exception while processing
> AddOrUpdateUserSettings [7/8/2020 2:02:00 PM] Executed
> 'AddOrUpdateUserSettings' (Failed,
> Id=caa3fab3-aece-43b2-9c16-bb1f4b78ec88) [7/8/2020 2:02:00 PM]
> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
> AddOrUpdateUserSettings. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client: Response
> status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0;
> ActivityId: 56c44578-b7c0-4cc9-aac8-5fc331371512; Reason: ({ [7/8/2020
> 2:02:00 PM]   "Errors": [ [7/8/2020 2:02:00 PM]     "Resource Not
> Found" [7/8/2020 2:02:00 PM]   ] [7/8/2020 2:02:00 PM] });.

Here is my cosmos db item json format:

```
{
    "id": "dfb2ac12-13e3-460a-ad12-4ea9c7e8ca8c",
    "UserUUId": "DevStreamuser2",
    "PreferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "DateFormat": "dd/MM/yy",
    "TimeFormat": "hh:mm",
    "Created": "2020-07-08T09:16:35.3093774Z",
    "Updated": "2020-07-08T13:49:57.6835166Z",
    "_rid": "7Sx-AJVl4ysDAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/7Sx-AA==/colls/7Sx-AJVl4ys=/docs/7Sx-AJVl4ysDAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-552e-aad7ccd101d6\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1594216197
}
```

`"PreferredLanguage"` property is a partition key. I am getting this error while trying to update the value for this property.

Below is my update method and also i am using cosmos DB SDK.

```
  public async Task<ItemResponse<T>> UpdateItemAsync(string id, T item)
        {
            return await _container.ReplaceItemAsync<T>(item, id);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, we cannot update the partition key of a document in a container.

[Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview) the link that mentions "If a property is your partition key, you can't update that property's value."

However, you can create a new document and remove the existing one in case you need to achieve above operation.